# James Joyce's Ulysses: why "wrote" and not "write"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, meaning-in-context

I am reading James Joyce's Ulysses at the moment, and I found this line:

> "Wonder did she wrote it herself."

Or a little bit earlier in the letter:

> So now you know what I will do to you (...) if you do not wrote.

Why is he using "wrote"? Is that an Irish dialect? Or poetic? Or simply wrong? I would've simply used "write".

Comment: The text of *Ulysses* is notoriously corrupt, with thousands of errors. There's a good brief discussion on [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(novel)#Publication_history).

Comment: I have observed this sort of error (in particular with write/wrote) in a number of people from what I took to be rural backgrounds.  Can't say that they were of Irish heritage, but it's not improbable.

Comment: What @StoneyB said. Interestingly, I find there are just 29 written instances of [Wonder did she **write** it herself doing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Wonder+did+she+write+it+herself+doing%22) in Google Books, compared to 45 for the "suspect" version [Wonder did she **wrote** it herself doing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Wonder+did+she+wrote+it+herself+doing%22). But the earliest "correct" version is dated 1961, whereas the earliest instance of the problematic one is 1967.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; it is appropriate on a site dealing with the vagaries of literature rather than English usage in general.

Answer (score 15):

Your second quotation is from a letter by Martha, writing to Bloom. It is a deliberate typo by the author, meant to show that the character Martha wasn't a good speller or typist. See, e.g. [Newman & Thornton *Joyce's Ulysses: The Larger Perspective*](https://books.google.com/books?id=drR_POHcB-QC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%22Wonder%20did%20she%20wrote%20it%20herself.%22&source=bl&ots=I8Q6W_M2AM&sig=e5QZ1NsYFcnnFDP2sRWD-Cjs1dY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7w7CVlKfUAhUB7oMKHT7QCcsQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22Wonder%20did%20she%20wrote%20it%20herself.%22&f=false).

Bloom is making reference to this very error when he then says "Wonder did she wrote it herself."

Some editions of *Ulysses* unfortunately correct one or both of these deliberate errors, thereby ruining the joke.

Comment: Yeah,... that makes a lot of sense, brilliant, thank you very much! Still trying to get to know James Joyce's writing, bit hard but worth it. :-)

Comment: That's beautiful. Kudos to you--and Joyce!

Comment: This is hardly about general English usage.

Comment: Oh, it isn't? Where should I put a question like this then? I have found the perfect answer here, given by someone who knows about Joyce.

Comment: @user8115296 If it's a question about literature, you can try asking it on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) `;-)`

Comment: Oh sorry, thought Literature is "using language".

Comment: Not a problem, @user8115296. If you have any new questions to ask about *Ulysses* or any other book, feel free to [ask it on Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :).

Comment: Sometimes one can't know a question isn't about general English usage until after one has the answer.

Comment: @user8115296 you should still pick this as the answer so that it doesn't seem like it's not answered :)

Comment: That's exactly what I will do and have done for the last 3 hours. Was very happy with my answer. Sorry again to have bothered you here under the wrong topic.